# Output recordset in VBA using condition

Tags: sql, vba, select

I am having some trouble here.

I have a csv database with 25 million lines with four columns: FIELD (from 1 to 5), DATEHOUR (in a format yyyyddmmhhmmssxxx , year, day, month, hour, minute, second and miliseconds), BOUND (south or north) and CATEGORY (from 1 to 10).

I am using the following code

```
Public Sub QueryTextFile()
    Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=Text;"

    Const SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Dados.csv WHERE Categoria=3;"

    Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Call Recordset.Open(SQL, ConnectionString, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
    Call Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset(Recordset)
    Recordset.Close
    Set Recordset = Nothing

End Sub
```

problem is that I, for example, want to get ONLY registers for FEBRUARY (month 02) and FIELD 3. How could I do that?

Thank you guys!

Comment: `CopyFromRecordset` will only return the first 65536 records.  `ADODB.Recordset.GetRows` will load the complete Recordset into an array that you can use to populate the worksheet.  If you can provide a download link for the CSV file I will help with code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Dados.csv 
WHERE 
Categoria = 3 AND
FIELD = 3     AND
DATEHOUR Like '######02*'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the file of this size and if all you need is a simple filter operation - you may want to just read it line by line and store matching lines. Here is an example:

Input file

```
FIELD,DATEHOUR,BOUND,CATEGORY
1,20030609100744914,south,2
2,19530310011542750,north,5
5,19780506121938486,south,6
3,19201602155516116,south,2
3,19381909204504683,north,2
4,19641002092156003,south,10
1,19142109082009062,south,8
5,19762306242234798,north,11
2,19261008163849534,south,2
1,19093003100715152,south,12
1,19282102090128629,north,2
5,19652606190400678,south,3
3,19162302062356493,south,3
5,20151605125616260,north,6
```

and the VBA function:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub filterData()

    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim csvLine As String

    Dim arrLine() As String      ' fields from the csv line, 0-based
    Const FIELD = 0: Const DATEHOUR = 1: Const BOUND = 2: Const CATEGORY = 3

    Dim arrResult() As String    ' string array for filtered data
    Dim idx As Long: idx = 1     ' current index in the array
    ReDim arrResult(idx To 1000) ' initial size

    ' read file line-by-line
    fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "dataFile.csv" _
            For Input As #fileNum

    While Not EOF(fileNum)
        Line Input #fileNum, csvLine
        ' 0-FIELD, 1-DATEHOUR, 2-BOUND, 3-CATEGORY
        arrLine = Split(csvLine, ",")

        ' check the condition for inclusion
        If arrLine(FIELD) = "3" And Mid(arrLine(DATEHOUR), 7, 2) = "02" Then
            If idx > UBound(arrResult) Then
                ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To UBound(arrResult) * 2)
            End If
            arrResult(idx) = csvLine
            idx = idx + 1
        End If
    Wend

    Close #fileNum

    ' trim excess entries
    ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 to idx - 1)

    ' display results in the spreadsheet (only up to 1mm)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").[a1].Resize(UBound(arrResult), 1) = Application.Transpose(arrResult)

End Sub
```

Here is the result you'll get in "Sheet1":

[image]

P.S.: Or you can just use UNIX `grep`...

P.S.S.: Also note, that if the result array will be larger than 1mm entries - you won't be able to display it in Excel. Code can be modified to limit the number of entries in array, display only part of the array, display it in multiple columns though or write the result array into another file.